# One-to-ones-ness of Group Elements

Tags: group-theory

I came along this theorem in a book, saying that if $a,b,c \in G$, where $G$ is a group, then if $ab = ac$, then $b=c$. It looks like if we assume that all elements in the set are functions (because, after all, we are composing functions when talking about groups), then each function is one-to-one. If $a$ is not a one-to-one function, we cannot assume the above statement. Am I right?

Comment: If a set of functions is a group with respect to the operation "composition of functions" then yes all those functions must be one-to-one.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Aren't all groups, in fact, a set of functions?

Comment: Well, yes and no.  You can represent all groups that way, but in general a group is just a set and a binary operation with certain properties.  For example the integers with addition is a group whose elements are numbers, not functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the fact that all groups are sets of functions, but it is necessary to be more specific. It is in fact true that any group $G$ is equivalent to a subgroup of the group of permutations of the elements of $G$.

Let us then represent each element $a \in G$ as a function--specifically, a permutation of the set $G$ itself, which we will denote by $f_a$, so that $f_a(x) = ax$. (We know this function to be a permutation because it has an inverse: $f_{a^{-1}}(x) = a^{-1}x$.)

The statement that $ax = ay \Rightarrow x = y$ for all $a,x,y \in G$ (the cancellation law) is then equivalent to $f_a(x) = f_a(y) \Rightarrow x = y$, so that the cancellation law is equivalent to the statement that all permutations of $G$ are one-to-one.

But all permutations are one-to-one anyway--a permutation is by definition a one-to-one correspondence--so that the cancellation law is always true for any group.

Comment: More precisely I'd say all groups are *isomorphic* to groups of functions, not that they are all simply sets of functions.

Comment: You're right, @GregoryGrant--hence the further specification. I never explicitly invoked the notion of isomorphism, but perhaps I should have.